# passing map with cmp function to function as a parameter

Tags: c++, dictionary

I have got this:

```
struct cmp_a_func {
   public:
   bool operator()(const char* a, const char* b) const {
      return std::strcmp(a, b) < 0;
   }
};

void func(std::map<const char *, const char *, struct cmp_a_func>& a) {
}

int main() {
    std::map<const char *, const char *, cmp_a_func> a;

    func(a);
}
```

So, I'm trying to pass my map a to func, but get this error:

> error: no matching function for call to `func(std::map<const char*,
>   const char*, cmp_a_func>&)`

**EDIT: Fixed now** - me, stupid blond, did not update prototype function in header:
void func(std::map& clients);

Thank you, guys!

Comment: In **func(a)**. Is that **a** the map?

Comment: @ Amanda Helgström: I have no errors compiling your code with gcc 4.7

Answer (score 0):

Try to remove `struct` word from the last argument in `func`

```
void func(std::map<const char *, const char *, cmp_a_func>& a)
```

Comment: While that `struct` isn't necessary, removing it seems unlikely to improve (or change) the situation (e.g., VC++ 18 and g++ 4.8.1 both accept the code either with or without the `struct` keyword present there).

Answer (score 0):

Successfully compiled your code with gcc (GCC) 4.7.3, with or without `struct` from the last argument in `func`.